# Flicker in IE11 on page load, but not in developer mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, flicker

I'm getting flicker on page load or postback of a coloured page body in IE11, on externally hosted site (ie. not from local disk).

The odd thing is it goes away if I either:

1. Open F12 developer tools
2. Add the site to trusted sites
3. Add the site to restricted sites

I've got a VM with IE9 which works fine. Works fine on Chrome.

I obviously cannot use any of the above as a solution!!!

This sample code has one link that switches between two pages. I've removed everything else, javascript, css files etc.

```
--- page1.html ---

<html>

<body style="background-color:#000000">
    <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```

And then an identical page2.html that refs back to page 1.

Clicking on the link flickers the background from white to black each time, unless using any of the "fixes" above!

Comment: Can you link the website? Actually seeing it in action would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sorry Justin, I haven't got a suitable place to permanently host the sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found another way to temporary fix this bug by adding an empty event handler through JS.

link such .js file to you html

fix_ie.js:

```
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){});
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Needs slight modification otherwise it will error out in IE8 (and possibly others): if(window.addEventListener){window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){});}

Comment: Yes correct. thank you. Also it is not necessery to create this event for all other browsers except IE 11. Therefore it will be better to check IE11 version and run this code only on this browser. But M$ removed the "if IE" directives, so some tricks may be used to detect IE11

Comment: Even if you don't touch the handler yourself, jQuery through 1.11 will trigger this bug, it's been fixed in new releases:  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535